# <T> Generic return type

Tags: java, generics

Explain the return type of this method:

```
 protected <T> T getClientHolder(String holderName, Class<T> clazz)
```

I know `T` refer to template and refer to the class which he get in its parameter but the position of `<T>` before T  is confusing.

Comment: It's not a template. That is c++ and it is distinctly different than a generic parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`<T>` is not the return type of that method. It means that the generic type parameter `T` is declared in the method `getClientHolder()`, and can only be used by that method. If you remove it, the compiler would treat the return type `T` of that method as a normal identifier, and would look for a class or interface named `T`.

If `T` was a generic type parameter declared in the class containing that method, there would be no need to declare `<T>` in this method.

```
protected <T>            T              getClientHolder(String holderName, Class<T> clazz)
          ---            -
          this is a      this is the 
          declaration    return type
          of a generic   of the method
          type parameter
```